# How to insert records from textboxes and checkboxes into a gridview on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert records from textboxes and checkboxes on an imagebutton click to a gridview. On every click, I want the records to be inserted into gridview and the old records added should remain unless I remove it from gridview. Help would be appreciated. Here is my codes in the GUI. Thanks!

```
<tr>
                <td align="center" class="tblborder">
                    <strong>Team Member(s)</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:23%" class="tblborder">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCTName" runat="server" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:imagebutton ID="btnCTName" name="btnChangeTeam" class="buttonsearch" runat="server" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/Images/search.jpg" Width="16px" />
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:27%" class="tblborder">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCTPosition" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:10%" class="tblborder">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCTSignOff" Runat="server"/>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:20%" class="tblborder">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCTDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:8%" class="tblborder">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgAddCT" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/addsign.png"
                        Height="20px" Width="20px" onclick="imgAddCT_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvChangeTeam" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="False">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="TeamName" ItemStyle-Width="30%" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Position" DataField="TeamPosition" ItemStyle-Width="20%"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sign Off" DataField="TeamSignature" ItemStyle-Width="10%"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="TeamDate" ItemStyle-Width="20%"/>
                            <asp:buttonfield ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="../Images/deletesign.png" commandname="ibtnDelete" HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ControlStyle-Height="20" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: So you have not written or tried any code yet! Just an aspx markup!

Comment: why not use jquery ajax for insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve data source of controls (GridView in this case) on postback. So options are to use view state, session etc. basically to persist original data during postbacks. These are also called as ASP.NET State Management techniques.

I purposely avoided using ViewState here because if your original dataset or datatable is huge it would kill the page. Even with Session there's a problem because it would get cleared after default session timeout value or whatever value you have set in config.

Although each one of these techniques has limitations, I am just going ahead to show you how it could be done with Session.

ASPX

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" />
        <asp:Button Text="Add" runat="server" OnClick="AddUsername" />
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var dt = GetInitialData();

        gv1.DataSource = dt;
        gv1.DataBind();

        Session["dt"] = dt;
    }
}

protected void AddUsername(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = Session["dt"] as DataTable;

    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Username"] = txt1.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    gv1.DataSource = dt;
    gv1.DataBind();

    Session["dt"] = dt;
}

private DataTable GetInitialData()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Username");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Username"] = string.Format("user name {0}", i);
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: hi @vnikhil may I if this method will save the information to database?

Comment: I have updated AddUsername method so that it stores newly added rows in Session too. Now saving to database is on your part. You have whole datatable available in Session.